# Consuming and Parsing JSON data from .Net web service using iOS 5 application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, web-services

My .Net web service url is : http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/iOSCalender/service1.asmx, this is having a method name called: "getDataFromMaster" which is returning JSON data as following(I do not have idea why different browser showing different output):

While running from safari:

```
[
{
    "Training_Code": "1234 ",
    "Training_Duration": "2hrs ",
    "Training_Startdate": "14/02/2013 15:00:00",
    "Training_Enddate": "14/02/2013 17:00:00",
    "Trainer_ID": 1,
    "Training_Location": "B-Wing Training room-4",
    "Comments": "C# training",
    "Keyword": "C#1234",
    "NumberofDays": 1
},
{
    "Training_Code": "4321 ",
    "Training_Duration": "16 ",
    "Training_Startdate": "17/02/2013 10:30:00",
    "Training_Enddate": "17/02/2013 17:30:00",
    "Trainer_ID": 2,
    "Training_Location": "A-Wing Training Room-6",
    "Comments": "Objective-C",
    "Keyword": "Obj-C4321",
    "NumberofDays": 2
}
]
```

while running from IE:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?><stringxmls="http://tempuri.org/">
[
{
    "Training_Code": "1234 ",
    "Training_Duration": "2hrs ",
    "Training_Startdate": "14/02/2013 15:00:00",
    "Training_Enddate": "14/02/2013 17:00:00",
    "Trainer_ID": 1,
    "Training_Location": "B-Wing Training room-4",
    "Comments": "C# training",
    "Keyword": "C#1234",
    "NumberofDays": 1
},
{
    "Training_Code": "4321 ",
    "Training_Duration": "16 ",
    "Training_Startdate": "17/02/2013 10:30:00",
    "Training_Enddate": "17/02/2013 17:30:00",
    "Trainer_ID": 2,
    "Training_Location": "A-Wing Training Room-6",
    "Comments": "Objective-C",
    "Keyword": "Obj-C4321",
    "NumberofDays": 2
}
]</string>
```

I'm trying to parse the JSON from my iOS application like this:

```
-(void)loadCalendarView
{
    if(x==0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Authentication failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
else if(x==1)
{
   [self ParseJSONdataFromMasterTraining];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];

}
}

-(void)ParseJSONdataFromMasterTraining
{

dispatch_sync(kBgQueue, ^{NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLMasterTraining];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}


-(void)fetchedData:(NSData*)responseData
{
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSLog(@"jsonDict = %@",json);
NSArray *trainingDetails = [json objectForKey:@"iOSCalender"];
NSLog(@"getDataFromTrainingMaster = %@",trainingDetails);

}
```

I'm unable to get data,my "trainingDetails" is showing null.

Note: I tried both "dispatch_sync" and "dispatch_async" method for this but still having same problem.

Could any one please guide me, where I'm going wrong and how to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: you don't has any entry in the WS output called `@"iOSCalender"`, so it is normal that `trainingDetails` gets a `null` value, can you `NSLog` the `json` dictionary and post the result?

Comment: My json dictionary is also null.My web service output or JSON data does not have @"iOSCalender".How Can I do this?

Comment: 1. I don't want be a trivial, but what encoding you use? In case of cp1251 the answer is obvious.
2. Could you please print responseData converted to NSString with encoding type 4?

Comment: Getting data like this: ResponseData = <0d0a0d0a 3c68746d 6c3e0d0a 0d0a2020 20203c68 6561643e 3c6c696e 6b207265 .....> What is encoding type 4? How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

OK your example JSON is an array of dictionaries.  Your code to get iOSCalendar will not work and should throw an error since an array doesn't have objectForKey:  That is if you where getting something in you JSON object.

Did you look at your err variable.  You should look at that if you are getting a null.

You can output the NSData as a string.

```
NSString *s = [NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData encoding: NSUTF8String];
```

Print that out and see what you got. Just looking at your data output, you are getting something that starts with

```
<html
```

That is not JSON

Comment: Yes, I'm getting <html .I have json data returned from web service as shown above. How to I set objectForKey for those data? How can I modify my code to get json data?Please help.

Comment: I'm trying to do like this:  
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    NSArray *arr = [json objectForKey:@"Training_Code"];
    NSLog(@"JSoN = %@",arr); I'm still getting null.

Comment: Is my json object correct? Asking because, there is nothing prior to square bracket [ , to pass to "ObjectForKey" method.